# When you find a trap, what do you know about it?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, traps

All I could find about this subject is in [Detecting a Hazard](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=669):

> When characters approach a hazard, they have a chance of finding the trigger area or mechanism before triggering the hazard.

> Anyone who succeeds becomes aware of the hazard, and you can describe what they notice.

But what does this mean? Do you only know that there's a trap, or the trigger of one, in that square? Do you know the whole trap statblock? Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Detection grants knowledge of its location

As you quote,

> [...] they have a chance of finding the trigger area or mechanism...

For some traps, this is just a pressure plate; for other Hazards, you *may* notice the blowdart holes lining the hallway, or the "oddly undisturbed corpse". Further information can and usually should be made available through appropriate Recall Knowledge and/or Seek actions.